# Django handling automatic data creation through URL's

Tags: django

hello  guys hopefully you guys are willing to work with a newbie I'm working in django and handling a google map (in jscript) which upon displaying a marker I have set a link that is clickable that opens a django url passing data regarding the location of that marker. If that data does not exist in the database I have created a definition in my view that does a check and populates the database with that data if it does not exist. Now the issue here is that what ever you type in for the url parameters ends up becoming populated in the database since there is nothing to validate it against regardless of whether you click in the google map or not. Now what I was looking to do was limit this database addition strictly to when a user clicks on a google map link, what would you guys recommend?

ajax, sessions  etc... ? and how to go about it an example per se?

Comment: Could you show your code and the error stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to have more info.

As a general rule, the http GET method shouldn't be used to change data. In this case, use a POST request, probably through AJAX.